# If $y= \frac1{1+x} + \frac2{1+x^2} + \frac4{1+x^4} + \dots + \frac{2^n}{1+x^{2^n}} $, then find $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> If $y= \dfrac1{1+x} + \dfrac2{1+x^2} + \dfrac4{1+x^4} + \dots + \dfrac{2^n}{1+x^{2^n}} $, then find $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$.

I am stuck up in this question. I tried taking log on both sides and generate some simplified expression but was unable to do so. Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: First read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) then learn about [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), if you don't want to read here's [another](https://math-on-quora.surge.sh) tutorial, though it's introduction does not apply to this site. . or you'll get downvotes.

Comment: I'm confused.  Did the question specifically **require** that $dy/dx$  be *simplified*?  **If not,** then, since the derivative of the sum = the sum of the derivatives, you could simply differentiate each fraction separately, and let the **unsimplified** result be your *final answer.*

Comment: yes the derivative would simplify

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac1{1+y}+\dfrac1{1-y}=\dfrac2{1-y^2}$$

Set $y=x,x^2,x^4,\cdots,x^{2^n}$ to find

$$y+\dfrac1{1+x}=\dfrac{2^n}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$$

Comment: It's derivative would simplify too but I'm unable to match up to the answer..

Comment: @user55124, What's the answer